# How to create a view that returns the last ten documents from a set of devices?

Tags: couchdb

Is it possible to create a view that receives a set of deviceIDs and returns the last 10 documents from each one of them?

The documents are in this format:

```
{
  "_id": "002b8ba94519abc038624601d718b967",
  "_rev": "1-6727616a5c51d5d271eb7458dbe8249c",
  "lat": -21.59941,
  "bl": 100,
  "ic": 1,
  "ax": -0.47,
  "ay": -0.59,
  "ch": 920,
  "t": 300.25,
  "lng": -48.370622,
  "timestamp": 1471454475140,
  "deviceID": "device1"
}
```

I need to get the last 10 documents sorted by timestamp in order to render a graph in a dashboard

What I have in mind is to do a GET request with an array as the keys parameter:

/telemetry/_design/name/_view/getLast10Docs?keys=["device1","device2","device3"]

And it should return something like:

```
{
  "device1": [ last 10 docs here],
  "device2": [ last 10 docs here],
  "device1": [ last 10 docs here]
}
```

Is it possible to do it all at once in just one view? Or should I do queries against each one of the deviceIDs in the the array separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think it's possible. You could group them by device and by timestamp but to get the 10 last one, you would need to apply a limit of 10 to a certain parameter wich is not possible.

The best approach would be to do map function on the **deviceId** and **timestamp**. From there, you could do a query on this view with `grouplevel=1` to get all the devices available. Then, for each devices, query this map using `?key['deviceId']&limit=10&descending=true`. This will get the 10 documents associated for this deviceId with the highest timestamp(most recent).

If making too much network request is not a good solution for you, you could also fetch the whole result and handle the data on the client side but I do not recommend this.

Comment: By looking at the documentation, it in fact didn't seem to have a solution for my case, so as you said, I created a view that returns a list of deviceIDs, and another that returns the last 10 docs for a specific deviceID. What I'm going to do next is fetch data only for the first device on the list, render the dashboard, and then fetch data for other devices on background, one by one.